# Programmatically setting Absolute URL inside image controls for .NET Facebook Application

Tags: .net, url, facebook, asp.net, absolute

The goal is to allow a function to be called from within an ASPX imagebutton control that is used as part of a form. The need for an absolute URL is that Facebook Canvas applications require them. So the rendered control should look something like

`<input type="image" src="http://myURL.com/images/submit.gif" />`

The ASPX markup might be something like `<asp:imagebutton runat="server" imageurl="<%= MyAbsoluteURLFunction("images/submit.gif)" %>" />`

My sample syntax is obviously incorrect, which is why I'm here. The reason I want to use an ImageButton is because it will have events attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of pointing to a method in your markup, why don't you set the absolute URL from your code? if you have a single image control it can be done in page_init/load, and if you're dealing with rows of image controls, say in a Repeater control, you can handle the OnRowDataBound event and set the properties.